# Play Console stacktrace for TiJSService

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I have an app with 100.000+ users and since Android 7 begun rolling out this stacktrace have begun showing up (only reported for Android 7.0). I use Ti SDK 5.5.1

It's being reported for: ti.modules.titanium.android.TiJSService.start

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3495)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap23(ActivityThread.java:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1674)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6524)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.getKrollObject(KrollProxy.java:450)
  at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.hasListeners(KrollProxy.java:948)
  at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.hierarchyHasListener(KrollProxy.java:956)
  at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.fireEvent(KrollProxy.java:752)
  at ti.modules.titanium.android.TiJSService.start(TiJSService.java:96)
  at ti.modules.titanium.android.TiJSService.onStartCommand(TiJSService.java:47)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3476)
```

Anyone who can point in any direction? I'm kinda lost as to the cause of this.

Comment: I had some issues with Android 7 devices prior to updating my app to Ti SDK 6.  Note that moving to sdk 6 will require updated versions of any android modules in your app. Pretty much all 3rd party modules have new versions available by now, though.

Comment: Had that thought as well. Only issue is we use an in-app-purchase module bought from marketplace that has not been updated :/

Comment: That's frustrating. Had that happen once, as well and had to work around it. You might check gitt.io to see if there is an OSS alternative.